# Formatting - Export as PDF - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, pdf, export

The below short VBA code exports multiple PDFs from a workbook, it cycles through the worksheets to see if anything is contained in cell A1 then exports as PDF only if the cell is populated.

```
Sub PrintPDFs()
    
    Const theValueToStop As String = ""
    Const theAddress As String = "A1"
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    timestamp = Format(Date, "mmddyyyy ")
    For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Range(theAddress).Value <> theValueToStop Then
    ws.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, Filename:= _
    ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & date & "marketstudy " & ws.Name & ".pdf"
    End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

This has worked perfectly for myself, however some of my colleagues are having difficulty with printing as it sometimes is formatted differently. I want it to always fit every worksheet onto a single PDF.

Appreciate any help given.

Comment: Add `ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesTall = 1` and `ws.PageSetup.FitToPagesWide = 1` before `ws.ExportAsFixedFormat`

Comment: Cheers! That appears to have worked in combination with .zoom = false